# accord avec COD

Tags: accord, compléments

Bonjour,

Voici la phrase qui me pose un problème.

> "Elle s'intéresse à la lecture sans que nous l'ayons **poussé** à
>   cela".

Comment accorder **poussé**? Si le COD est `l'`, ne faut-il pas mettre un `e` puisqu'on parle d'une fille ici?

Comment: Yes. See [this recent question and answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29539).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [L'accord du participe passé dans les temps composés](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29539/laccord-du-participe-pass%c3%a9-dans-les-temps-compos%c3%a9s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il faut mettre un `e` puisque l'on dit : **pousser qqun à faire qqch**.

Ainsi écrirais-je :

> "Elle s’intéresse à la lecture sans que nous l'ayons poussée à cela".

ou bien :

> "Elle s'intéresse à la lecture sans que nous l'y ayons poussée".

ou encore (plus-que-parfait du subjonctif:-)!) :

> "Elle s'intéresse à la lecture sans que nous l'y eussions poussée".

**EDIT**

Selon l'[académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/poser-probleme-et-poser-question) il faut dire **poser un problème**.