# What is the difference between the verb 'sortir' being conjugated with être or avoir?

Tags: verbes, conjugaison, auxiliaires

I have seen in many web sites that the verb 'sortir' can be conjugated in the past with either 'être' or 'avoir'. What is the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Être sorti* means "to <s>get out</s> have left" or "to go out":

> *Je suis sorti de la maison* - <s>I got out of the house</s> I left the house..
>
> *Je suis sorti avec Marcel* - I dated Marcel.

*Avoir sorti* means to put something outside:

> *J'ai sorti les poubelles* - I took the trash out.

Comment: Ces citations au petit bonheur, moi je les aime trop!

Comment: Si tu "got out", la maison était en train de bruler ou de s'écrouler.

Comment: @Lambie Eh bien ! Heureusement que j'en suis sorti alors :-)

Comment: The house was on fire and he got out. Il s'est sauvé ou Il a pu s'en sortir.

Comment: @Lambie Oui, j'avais déjà compris avec ton premier commentaire que le sens était trop fort face à *sortir*. J'ai rayé *get out* de ma réponse donc l'incident est clos.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few verbs that are composed with the verb être in the compound tenses (passé composé, plus-que-parfait, futur antérieur...).

You can memorise the most basic ones with the following mnemonic rule

**MRS DR VANDERTRAMPP**

> Monter, Rester, Sortir, Devenir, Retourner, Venir, Aller, Naître,
> Descendre, Entrer, Rentrer, Tomber, Revenir, Arriver, Mourir, Passer,
> Partir.
>
> Monter --> monté (went up)
>
> Retourner --> retourné (returned)
>
> Sortir --> sorti (went out)
>
> Venir --> venu (came)
>
> Arriver --> arrivé (arrived)
>
> Naître --> né (was born)
>
> Descendre --> descendu (went down)
>
> Entrer --> entré (entered)
> Rester --> resté (stayed)
>
> Tomber --> tombé (fell)
>
> Rentrer --> rentré (went back in)
>
> Aller --> allé (went)
>
> Mourir --> mort (died)
>
> Partir --> parti (left)
>
> Passer --> passé (passed)

See here:

http://bookshelf.mml.ox.ac.uk/2015/05/06/fun-with-grammar-heres-to-you-mrs-vandertramp/

Another mnemonic rule is given here (the so-called **La Maison d'être**):

https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/french/french-i/french-i-the-passe-compose/the-passe-compose-with-etre

These are all **intransitive** verbs (that is, they have **no direct object**) that communicate a certain kind of **movement**.

(Note that the **inverse is not necessarily true**. E.g. **Courir** meaning run is conjugated with **avoir**. Also, e.g., **voler** (fly), **rouler** (roll), **nager** (swim), **marcher** (walk), **sauter** (jump). Therefore *il a couru, nous avons nagé* and so on.)

Normally all these verbs (MRSDRVANDERTRAMPP and their compounds-parvenir, repartir, remonter, redescendre, ressortir, etc.) are conjugated with être. However, the following verbs are a bit tricky.

> Monter, Sortir, Retourner, Descendre, Passer, Rentrer

These can be used **transitively** (with a direct object), and when this happens, these verbs need **avoir** as the helping verb. In addition, there is a slight change in meaning.

> Elle est sortie. - She went out.
>
> Elle a sorti la voiture - She took the car out.

For more you may consult the following page

https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/auxiliary-verbs-2/

Être is also used to form the compound tenses of **Reflexive Verbs** and the **Passive Voice** of **Transitive Verbs**. E.g.

> Je me suis promené(e). Le pont a été démoli. La porte était ouverte par le concierge.

Monter and descendre also take avoir in such expressions as:

> Ils ont monté l'escalier. J'ai descendu la rue.

Note also that for a few verbs like **demeurer, changer, grandir, vieillir** (respectively, change, stay/remain, grow, pass, grow old),  there is a **difference** in meaning between expressing **action** (conjugation with avoir) and **state** (être). Cf.,

> Il y a demeuré pour soigner sa mère (action).
>
> Il est demeuré insensible à nos prières (state).
>
> Elle a beaucoup grandi au collège (action).
>
> Comme elle est grandie (= Quelle grande elle est) (state).
>
> La journée avait passé tranquillement (action: had passed).
>
> Le danger était passé (state: had passed-was past).

Above may be used as guidelines for further reading.

See also the relevant discussion here

[Dr and Mrs Vandertrampp](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16789/dr-and-mrs-vandertrampp)

(thanks @jlliagre for pointing me out this discussion)

Comment: Note that these famous elsewhere but unknown in France Vandertrampps have already been introduced to FSE [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16789/dr-and-mrs-vandertrampp).

Comment: Désolé! Bien sur je ne crois pas avoir réinventer la roue☺! Je ne l'ai pas su. Je n'étais pas par ailleurs membre de fse à 2015. Je voulais seulement donner un récapitulatif pour guider la personne qui a posé la question.

Comment: Pas de problème. J'aurais du y penser quand j'ai répondu mais je les avais oublié...

Comment: *oubliés* même.